# Paying $5$ each of $3$ people when each only have coins of $10$, $15$ and $20$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> How can $3$ friends pay $5$ cents each to enter some place, when they only have coins of $10$, $15$ and $20$ cents (unlimited of them)?

I started by noticing that each of them must pay an odd quantity and only giving a coin of $15$ to another person changes the parity of both people(the one who gives and the one who receives. So if every one starts at paying an even quantity ($0$), some changes must be done to ensure every one of them has payed an odd quantity and then paying with coins of $10$ or $20$ until you have payed all of it, but this is imposible as you cannot go from $000_2$ to $111_2$ changing two digits at a time.

---

So here is the problem, my conclusion is that this is not possible, but the problem is in a book of problems, which the logical thing is that it has a valid answer.

Comment: Let the people be labeled $A,B,C$.  Have person $B$ give $A$ a 15cent piece and $A$ gives $B$ a 10cent piece.  Similarly $C$ gives $A$ a 15cent piece and $A$ gives $C$ a 40cent piece.  Now, $A$ pays the entry fee of 15cents to the doorman.  All of $A,B,C$ each have their net worth decreased by exactly 5cents.

Comment: @MrYouMath What should you put as title?

Comment: @JMoravitz submit that as an answer please

Comment: @JMoravitz also you have a typo "$A$ gives $C$ a$ \40$ should be 10 cent piece